# Google is using placeholder text from the page in the search results rather than the page title of "Home"

Tags: seo, google, search, title

The search result for Google incorrectly appears as "Enter your text here" for my website. The title is correct in the HTML code: "Home".

[image]

Why is this happening and what can I do to correct it?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that "Home" is not a great title.  Your page title should be something like:

> Kallpachay Summer Camp

"Home" is a generic title used by lots of sites.  Google is ignoring it because it doesn't describe your site at all.

The text that Google is choosing is from a heading tag in the page source: `<h2 class="Title ospfxwcb50dd00a19f19ba935c9a031c21957dossfx">Enter your text here</h2>`  Google isn't very smart about choosing that text.   It doesn't describe your site much better than "Home" does.  It also doesn't appear on your rendered page; likely because it is hidden by CSS.

In addition to a better page title for your home page, you should remove that hidden `h2` or replace the text with something better.

Comment: While the OP is new to this stuff, I would suggest removing the hidden h2. Just in case.